# DATABASE - tables connection

Tags: sql, database

[TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvvJD.png)

I have this DB where the product have a PART NUMBER and that PN has many conditions (New, Overhauled, Used, Repairable) and that same PN + CONDITION can be stored at several boxes and the same box can have other PN. I´ve made the tables (link at the beginning)
I'm having problems with defining the PK of BOX-STORAGE and how to connect them so I can insert data on both table.

Comment: Don't post images unless they show something that cannot be illustrated in text. Table definitions can easily be posted as text, which makes it much easier for someone else to set up your working environment to test. See [ask], and take the [tour] you were offered when you posted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.